# How to save an array from MATLAB to database?

Tags: arrays, database, matlab

I have an array from MATLAB like this :

```
c2 =

     1
     1
     1
     2
     2
```

and I want to save it in my database. How can I store it in a cell or like json?
Every time I run my algorithm, a new array is created and I want to save it in my database from MATLAB. How can I do it?

This is how you create the array from MATLAB:

```
c2=iris(r1(p+1:end),5)
```

Comment: You can save it in using save of matlab why do you need database/json if matlab already supports writing to file and reading it ? https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com

Comment: I want to save it to the database to get it from there with php and display it to the user .

Comment: I use Laravel and i want to make graphs with output from my algorithm (C2 array)  with Lavacharts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much.
Finally I turned the array to string with mat2str(c2)

`con=database('databaseName','root','');
colnames={c2}
data={mat2str(c2)}
datainsert(con,tablename,colnames,data)
close(con)`

and i and saved it in the database.
Then i use substr() to return part of a string with no [] and explode to Split a string by string.

Answer (score 0):

Since R2016b json strings can be created/read using the commands [jsonencode](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/json-format.html) and [jsondecode](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/json-format.html).  Those commands would be used in conjunction with file io functions like `fopen`, `fprintf` and `fclose` to read/write the actual file.

There are also multiple json toolboxes available - just do a web search to find them all.  These can be used in the current version of MATLAB, or in older versions that don't support the above functions.

The easiest way to write to a database is using the [Database Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/products/database.html).  However writing your own interface is not hard.  However it depends on the exact database you're using and its specific API.